# Is Islam only Praying? Isn't Muslim community a big deal in Islam?

Tags: support

I asked a question about Islam idea according to Hadith and Quran about Muslim's world. And it became on-hold and closed.

Why can not we discuss about Islam Rawayat for politics view. Is Islam only Pray, Fast, Zakat, Haj? Isn't the basis of Islam about government and Muslims world.

I Believe Islam Have very wide view about these situations. Why should only discuss about existence of Jin or drinking water sitting?!? Is Islam a HOBBY in your view that can't answer vital concerns like politics from Quran, Hadith?

Comment: I will appropriate you if you let me know why it deserve -1 dislike??

Comment: The catch with political topics is that it is always two sides to it. You won't get an agreement from all users that Saudi is the devil and Iran is an Angel, or vice verse.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Muslim community is a big deal in Islam. But just because a question is relevant to the interests of some, many, most, or even *all* Muslims [does not make it a good question here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/22).

We are a Q&A site *about the topic of Islam*, but it is important to note that we are not a typical Internet forum, nor are we an Islamic site. Many of the types of questions that would work well on one of those [just plain don't work here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).  As far as Stack Exchange is concerned, questions — [real questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) — can't just be topics for discussion or solicitations of opinions, neither can they be rhetorical questions to prove a point: Questions here are expected to be *practical and answerable*.

Political questions, for the most part, do not meet that criteria. They are typically about controversial contemporary situations in which there are very strong partisan leanings; you will not attract actual *answers* with this question, you'll only attract [argument and debate](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22) from each side trying to prove why their "Truth" is more correct. The whole thread will [just become a popularity contest](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591/22), which the site is just not geared to handle.

The Stack Exchange model was built under a number of foundational principles, one big one of which is to cut through the noise (e.g. argument, debate, tangential discussion) that already plagues existing Internet fora and just give people the actual *answer* to their actual *question*. If you ask a question in which there is a significant difference of opinion (i.e. one that doesn't have an actual *answer*), especially when it's loaded with rhetoric and bias, all that does is *bring the same argument here* rather than help *anybody*.

---

As to [your question *in particular*](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28010/22), I would bring to your attention the following from our [be nice policy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice):

> **Don't be a jerk**. These are just a few examples. If you see them, flag them:
>
> …
>
> - **Bigotry of any kind**. Language likely to offend or alienate individuals or groups based on race, gender, sexual orientation, religion, etc. will not be tolerated. At all. (Those are *just a few examples*; when in doubt, just don't.)

We are a pluralistic site; "Islam" so far as this site is concerned includes *everyone who self-identifies as Muslim*, and we are open to *everybody*. As such, *all posts*, not to mention *all users*, are expected to treat others with respect here, whether they deserve it or not. As such, any posts that say — even *imply* — that any particular group deserve our hatred are not welcome here, nor are posts which are likely to instigate hatred against any particular group.

If you actually have a *real* question that you need an actual *answer* for, you can take the time to write it [politely and with respect](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1200/22) (see also the advice in our help centre on "[How do I ask a good question?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)")

If, however, your post is just thin excuse to call out what you see as atrocities committed by the Saudis (which is exactly what it looks like to me), it is wholly inappropriate here. Frankly, the only reason I haven't already flagged your post as offensive and had it removed completely was because you're relatively new here and I'm willing to give you the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Indeed I gratitude you for not Closing my post! I have to mention you that a good question needs some explanation. I used Saudi for instance.  When you want to explain fruits you mention apple for instance it does not mean orange is not a fruit! If you have attend enough to my question I don't ask for any opinion. I asked for Quran or related Hadith in Islam about acting for political aspects. Is there any Politic view in Islam in Hadith?

Comment: Ok I will Post another Question, this time based on your view, Let see what will be your opinion about that.

Comment: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28016. Let see what will be the reason for closing this post this time?! You should know that now I'm not responsible for Answers or comments that are opposite to Your rules!

Comment: @hope All you've done is demonstrate that giving you the benefit of the doubt was actually a poor decision on my part. I have now removed both of your posts for being offensive, for exactly the reasons I just explained.

Comment: Yes I see. Can you explain me what was the problem in my second post: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28016. What about that is suffering you, Sir!!

Comment: I see you don't belive in at least Human Rights : Freedom of speech. I obey all your rules in my Second post. Who is really offensive! I Think you should delete this post too!!!

Comment: Good Luck with this one : http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28017

Comment: @HOPE Stop wasting my time.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your political question is not that it is unrelated to Islam. It is indeed a question about Islam. The problem with your question is that it is not a question that has an indisputably *correct* answer. This site, as well as all of the other StackExchange sites are intended for objective questions and answers. We are not equipped to handle people's opinions. That doesn't mean these aren't good or important questions; it just means that this is not the place for them.

---

**Additional information about your specific question**

You wrote in your question,

> I'm worry about that the Judgment day we be partner in these crimes because of our silence. Is it true? Are we condemned to be partner with them? Will God ask us for These crimes, too?

What information are you asking for here? Your question assumes that the Saudi government is evil and it also states `"One who is cruel and one who is silent about that are equal."` So you've already answered your own question. If the Saudi government is evil and if you are silent about it, then you are equal to the Saudi government.  I can logically deduce that just by taking the statements of fact from your question and applying them logically.

So in order for this to be a question at all, you must be asking whether the Saudi government is really evil.  That is a matter of opinion and is off-topic on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Do you attend what was my question. I asked for Hadith and Quran verses about what occurs in the world and our responsibility that is in our burden. Did Islam has any claims about that. I mention an example in my question to illustrate my concern. It's a pure question. Why when you ask "Is there anything in Islam about Hijab" is considered a true question, but when I ask "Is there anything in islam about politics and other regims" is not a valid question!!!??

Comment: @HOPE "Is there anything in Islam about Hijab?" is **not** a good question. It is far too broad. I have added to my answer above.  See that edit.

Comment: This stateme that is Saudi criminal is in politicsubject and I asked it there. One another time I repeat my Question: I am seeking for hadith or Quran verses about this situation. Saudi is a example for illustration. Indeed what I say "One who is cruel and one who is silent about that are equal." is a logical statement not Hadith Not verses.

Comment: @HOPE in that case my suggestion would be to remove the example which is distracting and makes the question seem to be about politics. Then it can be reopened.

Comment: Ok I will think about it...

Comment: I see no problem in that question. it can be answered based on Quran and Hadith and not based on personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is COMPLETELY ISLAMIC... but not every question is to be asked and not every answer is to be given.

I mean if you ask me if XYAHSWEWGB is a murderer/bastard or not? while the person in question is holy to many... then you are asking the wrong question from the beginning at the wrong place.

Social mattes are very important. If I am a brutal pain in the neck... should you say that to me?

I don't know who or what you consider dear... but let's say you consider country XYAZS dear and love... it would be difficult for you to hear people criticizing it...

You would fight back as حبك للشيء يعمي ويصم meaning your love for something will make you deaf and blind... and that it is when this community will go south!

Comment: OK. You're right. But dear friend every man has a believe and it doesn't mean that others believe are wrong or right. You should not compare a man believe with another man. Main idea and basis of Islam is that every man with every believe have a clear way and order to obey from God. What I or you dear friend, realize from God's orders, give us different path of life. A man became Vahabi, other Sunni, other Shia and etc. But All of them believe in their path.

Comment: Question is that What is God order in the situations that you see (unrelated to what side you are) when see some groups are out of Islam in your view point. Any Hadith related to these situations? Is there any simultaneous situation in islam?

Comment: Habibi...my brother...your not getting the point... This is an open community from all sects. If you say anything against Iranians...then its against the Shias and people in the community would go against you... if you say anything against the Saudis then the Sunni-Wahhabi would become against you.
The community is open to A CERTAIN EXTENT... its not open 100%! I am sure there are narrations that can help indirectly but still this isn't the place for you to be asking them!